# object of type 'method' has no len()

Tags: django

I am adding pagination on django, it is giving error 
"object of type 'method' has no len()"

```
    allCategoryValue = category.objects.all
    paginators = Paginator(allCategoryValue, 3)
    pages = request.GET.get('abc')

    try:
        allCategory = paginators.page(pages)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        allCategory = paginators.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        allCategory = paginators.page(paginator.num_pages)
    context = {'allCategory':allCategory}   
    return render(request,'addCategory.html',context)
```

Comment: all() is a method.. call it and it should work

Answer (score 2):

The `category.objects.all` is a method. So, instead of writing

```
allCategoryValue = category.objects.all
```

You should write

```
allCategoryValue = category.objects.all()
```

Now, it calls the method and it returns the expected results.

Comment: That solved my problem, thanks! Before implementing pagination, it was also accepting allCategoryValue = category.objects.all . Why?

Comment: you were assigning the method `category.objects.all`. That's not the behaviour that you wanted, but it's syntactically right. As this answer solves your problem, feel free to mark it as the solution

Comment: actually I am not the one who posed the question, but thanks anyway :)